# How to find the first used cell in the excel sheet dynamically in VBA?

Tags: vba, excel

```
info.Worksheets("sheet1").UsedRange().Select
    ActiveCell.SpecialCells(xlFirstCell).Select
```

Comment: This does not work for me. How to find it?

Comment: `Worksheets("Sheet1").UsedRange.Cells(1).Select`

Answer (score 2):

Sadly the first cell in `UsedRange` may not actually be used.  For example:

```
Sub ExamineUsedrange1()
    MsgBox ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Address(0, 0)
End Sub
```

However:

[image]

where **B2** is not used.  It is better to use:

```
Sub ExamineUsedrange2()
    Dim r As Range
    Set r = Cells.Find(What:="*", _
                    After:=Cells(Rows.Count, Columns.Count), _
                    LookAt:=xlPart, _
                    LookIn:=xlFormulas, _
                    SearchOrder:=xlByRows, _
                    SearchDirection:=xlNext, _
                    MatchCase:=False)
    MsgBox r.Address(0, 0)
End Sub
```

[image]

Comment: It's cool to see how Excel maintains B2 as *used* even if it has no value. Your answer is great and your method to get the *real first used cell* is really useful. Thanks for sharing it